# Obtaining expectation of a variable given a conditional expectation

Tags: expected-value

Is there any mathematical association between the conditional expectation of a variable  given another variable, and the unconditional expectation of that variable?

I realise that given a joint distribution between $A$ and $B$, we can find $E[A]$ by first finding the marginal distribution of $A$.

However, suppose we know what is $E[A|B]$, is it possible to obtain $E[A]$ from this alone using any mathematical property?

Answer (score 0):

No. You also need additional information to obtain $\mathrm{E}(A)$. In particular,  the probability distribution of $B$ helps.  We can write

$$
\mathrm{E}(A) = \sum_b \mathrm{E}(A|B=b) \mathrm{P}(B=b)
$$

This means that if you know $\mathrm{E}(A|B)$ and $\mathrm{P}(B)$, then you can calculate $\mathrm{E}(A)$.

Comment: The answer of Kota Mori is perfect but note that what was written is also referred to as the tower property of expectations: E(E(A|B)) = E(A).

Comment: @mlofton Thanks.  Also called "law of total expectation".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation